# Referencing class names between SASS modules

Tags: css, sass

I'm confused how to reference my SASS module class name in another module. I have a `Contact` page module and a `PhoneNumber` module. In certain context on this page, I'd like to change the button inside the `PhoneNumber`. Using simplified example for clarity:

```
// src/pages/contact/index.module.scss

@use 'src/components/PhoneNumber/index.module' as phoneNumber;

.page {
    phoneNumber.container {
        :global(.button) {
            background-color: pink;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, I'm not sure how to reference `.container` class name of `PhoneNumber` component.

Comment: Please add more information. Put the code of index.module.

Comment: That's the code of `index.module.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

(1) If you include variables imported by directive `@use ... as namespace` you have to call them using the added namespace with character `$` as well. So you have to call the variable with `phoneNumber.$container`, not: 'phoneNumber.container'.

(2) If you use a variable as element/id/class-name you have to wrap variables in `#{$hereMyVariable}` at all.

So try following code:

```
.page {
    
    .#{phoneNumbers.$container}{
        :global(.button) {
            background-color: pink;
        }   
    }

}
```

FURTHER EXPLANATION

Rule `@use` loads mixins, functions, and variables from other Sass stylesheets so you can use them. To separate same variables/mixins/functions names from different stylesheets you can separate them to different namespaces by `@use scssFileName as myNamespace`.

Now you can call i.e. variables with same name `namespace1.$container` and `namespace2.$container` from different stlesheetswith different values. Mixins works the same way just without `$`.

So: if you load `@use filepath/filename as phoneNumber` to your stylesheet and call `phoneNumber.container` SASS is looking to the other stylesheet for a function or mixin named `container`. From the context of you simplified example I assume you want to call a variable with the name of the class. Than you need to use `$` and the brackets.

(Notice: But if you want just to name your class `phoneNumber.container` you should write `.phoneNumber.container`so SASS will interpret it as classname and not as reference to the namespace of the other stylesheet ...)

Wider explanations how to use `@use` can be find in the excellent official docs: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: What variable? I don't understand why all SASS module tutorials talk about variables. I don't want variables, I'm just using a class name.

Comment: @RoboRobok I added some further explanations. Hope it helps. Otherwise: more real code would be helpful ... ;-)